# Programmatically summing consecutive subsections (of increasing lengths) from a list

Tags: python

I have a list, which in my actual situation contains 512 items, all floats. For illustration, consider this smaller list of integers:

```
[23, 46, 20, 89, 102, 6, 25, 86]
```

I need to create:

1. A list combining values of the first two, next two and so on elements from the original list (resulting in 256 elements)

   ```
   [(23 + 46), (20 + 89), (102 + 6), (25 + 86)]
   -> [69, 109, 108, 111]
   ```
2. A list combining values of the first four, next four and so on elements from the original list (resulting in 128 elements)

   ```
   [(23 + 46 + 20 + 89), (102 + 6 + 25 + 86)]
   -> [178, 219]
   ```

And so on, for lengths equal to powers of 2, up through...

6. A list combining values of the first 64, next 64 and so on elements from the original list (resulting in 8 elements)

I cannot figure out a simple yet effective approach for how to do it in a loop, rather than manually building each one. Any hint would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide sample input (may be with lesser number of values), along with expected output? Also please provide your effort as well

Comment: Manually to create six lists can be done easily, but as I am taking more on the project (processing RAM capacity booking for some PCs may increase exponentially by number of units added to the stack over time) I think I will need in the future some algorithm, not to create manually another lists for the next batch of PCs that are added to the stacks. Hence the need for an iterative approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be handily accomplished with the [`chunked`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.chunked) function of the [More Itertools](https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/) package (and the ever-useful [list comprehension](https://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/)).

`chunked` is a readymade iterator that breaks the sequence into chunks of the specified size, e.g.:

```
from more_itertools import chunked

ram_entries = [23, 46, 20, 89, 102, 6, 25, 86]
for chunk in chunked(ram_entries, 2):
    print(chunk)
```

Prints:

```
(23, 46)
(20, 89)
(102, 6)
(25, 86)
```

A function to process a list in the way you described could look like this:

```py
from more_itertools import chunked

def sum_chunks(input_list, chunk_size):
    """Return a list of sums of consecutive chunks from a list."""
    return [sum(chunk)
            for chunk in chunked(input_list, chunk_size)]

def process_ram(ram_entries):
    """Return a list of lists, each summing chunks of increasing size.

    Chunk size is powers of 2 from 2 to 64, inclusive.
    """
    # Could also just be chunk_sizes = [2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64]
    chunk_sizes = [2**n for n in range(1, 7)]
    return [sum_chunks(ram_entries, chunk_size)
            for chunk_size in chunk_sizes]
```

---

Of course, this could be done "all at once", without naming intermediary variables/functions...

```
from more_itertools import chunked

def process_ram(ram_entries):
    return [[sum(chunk) for chunk in chunked(input_list, chunk_size)]
            for chunk_size in [2**n for n in range(1, 7)]]
```

...but personally I think that's a lot less readable. Brevity is good, until it impedes clarity.

Answer (score 2):

[One of the recipes in the `itertools` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) shows you how to group elements from an iterable together (`grouper`)

```py
from itertools import zip_longest
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
```

Example of usage

```py
l = [23, 46, 20, 89, 102, 6, 25, 86]
lis1 = [sum(i) for i in grouper(l, 2)]
lis2 = [sum(i) for i in grouper(l, 4)]
```

Comment: Yep, apologise, I have confused the solutions with the one from another forum. I deleted the comment. Solution is equaly workable, as I tested a few minutes ago. How can I point to this as a correct solution also, as I cannot tick two solutions equaly valid?

Comment: @Gab2021 Since, as you mentioned, you can only accept one answer, that's pretty much what upvotes are for.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own little state machine that keeps track of the current group and creates and switches to the next group when the size of the previous group exceeds your required group size.
I have created an `ElementGroups` class here that accepts a `group_size` as a constructor parameter:

```
class ElementGroups:

    def __init__(self, group_size):
        self.groups = []
        self.current_group = 0
        self.length = 0
        self.group_size = group_size

    def add(self, element):
        # If groups is empty, create the first group with the element and increment length 
        if not self.groups:
            self.groups.append([element])
            self.length += 1
            return

        # When the group size reaches the size of your required group size, set length to 0 and create and append a new group
        if self.length % self.group_size == 0:
            self.current_group += 1
            self.length = 0
            self.groups.append([])

        self.groups[self.current_group].append(element)
        self.length +=1
```

Now you can create a list of these state machine objects with the required group sizes. In your case, the group size of the `n`th group is `2^n` where `n` is a *one based index*:

```
groups = [ ElementGroups(2 ** i) for i in range(1, 7)]
```

Now you have to do nothing else but iterate through your list and add each element to all these groups. Here I'm using `elements` which is simply a range from 1-512 :

```
elements = range(1, 512) 
for element in elements:
        for group in groups:
               group.add(element)
```

Now you can access the individual groups through indices. The following is the first set of groups which are groups of two:

```
groups[0].groups
```

You can now reuse the `ElementGroups` class to create groups of any size. Just pass in the size as a constructor parameter.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I am not so knowledgeable to understand the code (I am a beginner with OOP), but will give you a plus.

Answer (score 1):

For a simpler answer:

```
import random

LIMIT = 512 #element count
allLists = []




elements = [round(random.randint(0,50) / 7,2) for i in range(LIMIT)]#for a sample element list

for i in range(1,7):#7 is the list count (1,2,3,4,5,6)
    count = pow(2,i)#we get power of 2 so 2,4,8,16,32,64
    allLists.append([])#this empty list will be filled with arrays of 2,4,8,16,32,64 elements in order.
    for jump in range(0,LIMIT,count):
        allLists[-1].append([])#this empty list will be filled with 2,4,8,16,32,64 elements in order
        for inc in range(count):
            allLists[-1][-1].append(elements[jump+inc])


for i in allLists:
    print(len(i))
```

Simply, you just place arrays to in an bigger array. like

[ [ [element1,element2] , [element3,element4] , [element5,element6],[element7,element8] ]->2 element-arrays in first level

[ [element1,element2,element3,element4],[element5,element6,element7,element8] ]->4 element-arrays in second level and so on...

output is:

```
256
128
64
32
16
8
```

Comment: I presume I have to split the line that begins with "elements =" and the "for i in range ..." to be the next / a separate line

Comment: It's called list comprehension, a python feature that allows to create a for loop in a single line. It's just to create a sample filled with floats. You will use your input instead of elements variable. so that line will be a single line.

Comment: Ok, thanks for detailed explanation, I marked your input as positive.

Comment: I think this solution might have worked also, but once I got itertools package solving my problem I found it as more effective solution because I have identified in that package other functions that looks like fit for further tasks that I have in my mind for the project, tasks that were not tackled yet.